# Problema com a configuração do Spring Security

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

Galera estou com problema no seguinte cenário:

Tenho dois projetos, onde um é o projeto de resource e o outro projeto é o servidor de autenticação, ambos projetos foram construídos com spring boot.

O projeto com o servidor de aplicação está funcionando normalmente com spring-security Oauth2, aqui não tenho nada a se queixar. No projeto do cliente estou com um problema, quando eu rodo a aplicação pelo spring boot, não há erro algum, porém quando eu passo as duas aplicações para o tomcat (servidor externo), o projeto do cliente cria uma solicitação de requisição para o servidor de autenticação no contexto do spring, mas como o tomcat não terminou de publicar os projetos a aplicação trava nessa parte.

Realizei também um teste para verificar se subindo somente o projeto do cliente pelo spring boot(tomcat embutido), o mesmo não cria essa requisição e some o projeto normalmente.

a propriedade que cria a requisição fica no application.properties e está na seguinte maneira:

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyUri=http://localhost:8080/partner-interface-oauth2/oauth/token
```

Obrigado pela atenção e pela a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvemos o problema adicionando a chave pública no arquivo de propriedades com o parâmetro security.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyValue.
Assim a classe ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration não precisa fazer uma requisição para servidor de autenticação no startup;